# CdiJtaProcessEngineConfiguration requests Transaction Manager before its is loaded

Tags: java, activiti, apache-tomee

I am successfully able to get Activiti working with the JtaProcessEngineConfiguration and separately with the CdiStandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration.

But i am not able to get the CdiJtaProcessEngineConfiguration working, an example of my config is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans <a href="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

" rel="nofollow">http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

</a>    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/TransactionManager"></property>
        <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.cdi.CdiJtaProcessEngineConfiguration">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="transactionsExternallyManaged" value="true" />

        <property name="dataSourceJndiName" value="openejb:Resource/jdbc/AppDS" />
        <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" value="false"/>

        <property name="jobExecutorActivate" value="false"/>
        <property name="asyncExecutorEnabled" value="true"/>
        <property name="asyncExecutorActivate" value="true"/>
        <property name="history" value="audit"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

With the error being

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [TransactionManager] is not
>   bound in this Context. Unable to find [TransactionManager].

and the stack trace is as follows

```
2016-11-29 13:47:37 ERROR ProcessEngines:174 - Exception while initializing process engine: Error creating bean with name 'processEngineConfiguration' defined in resource loaded through InputStream: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager';
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in resource loaded through InputStream: Invocation of init method failed;
nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [TransactionManager] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [TransactionManager].
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processEngineConfiguration' defined in resource loaded through InputStream: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager';
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in resource loaded through InputStream: Invocation of init method failed;
nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [TransactionManager] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [TransactionManager].
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary
```

I am not sure what to try next

The app server i am using is Tomee-plus 1.7.3

Cheers
Adam

[Edit 1] Please note the you need to load the JtaProcessEngineConfiguration manual when the app is ready but CdiStandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration and CdiJtaProcessEngineConfiguration are loaded automatically via the ActivitiExtension class.

[Edit 2]
When looking up the Transaction Manager as follows (as per @Romain Manni-Bucau Suggestion) inside an extended JtaProcessEngineConfiguration (without cdi)

```
    try {
        InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
        try {
            transactionManager = (TransactionManager) initialContext.lookup("openejb:Resource/TransactionManager");
        } finally {
            initialContext.close();
        }

    } catch (NamingException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
```

I get the following exception trace

```
2016-12-06 09:16:35 ERROR TestJtaProcessEngineConfiguration:29 - Name     "Resource/TransactionManager" not found.
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name "Resource/TransactionManager" not found.
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.IvmContext.federate(IvmContext.java:199)
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.IvmContext.lookup(IvmContext.java:151)
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.IvmContext.lookup(IvmContext.java:119)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
<snip>
```

[Edit 3] trying to use "java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.openejb.core.OpenEJBI‌​nitialContextFactory" results in the following stack trace.

```
Cannot instantiate class: org.apache.openejb.core.OpenEJBInitialContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.openejb.core.OpenEJBInitialContextFactory]
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:674)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
```

But using a jndi string of "openejb:TransactionManager" works

**SUCCESS**
the working config uses a jndiName property as follows.

```
<property name="jndiName" value="openejb:TransactionManager"></property>
```

Comment: Try to change value of property to "java:comp/env/TransactionManager".  Maybe this will help. But the general problem is that jndi-name "TransactionManager" is not bound in the namespace "java:comp"

Comment: @MaximKreschishin Thank you for the reply, I understand that, its kinda not that simple tho.  
  
The JtaProcessEngineConfiguration is able to lookup the TransactionManager but it is called alot later in the Application Deploy Cycle.  
  
With some dodgyness and tomfoolary I am to get the CdiJtaProcessEngineConfiguration to load the Transaction Manager later in the Application Deploy cycle too, but it is far from Production Safe code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @Romain Manni-Bucau help the solution is a jndi name of "openejb:TransactionManager"

My edit to allow me to accept @Romain Manni-Bucau answer was rejected, posting the correct answer here.

Answer (score 1):

What about using openejb:Resource/TransactionManager which is available as soon as the container is started (even before any deployment)? This will make any code relying on the transaction manager not depending on the startup lifecycle.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but,

I was unable to lookup up the Transaction Manager via "openejb:Resource/TransactionManager", please see my above edit.

Comment: maybe set java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.openejb.core.OpenEJBInitialContextFactory if hibernate runs in an unmanaged thread

Comment: Please see edit 3, using java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.openejb.core.OpenEJBI‌​nitialContextFactory gave a stack trace but using "openejb:TransactionManager"  works (without any properties to InitialContext)

is this invalid from a Tomee pov?

Comment: no it is valid, the Resource is not used for the tx mgr (see org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler#createTransactionManager)